# iOS:Swift Access button in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

**`ViewController.swift`**

```
@IBOutlet weak var btn_stop: UIButton!
```

**`AppDelegate.swift`**

```
let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as! ViewController

viewController.btn_stop.hidden=false
```

**Error** - gives me Fatal error & app Crash

Comment: Why you accessing button from app delegate. you should access it from view controller it self!

Answer (score 1):

Access your ViewController via the rootViewController option:

```
let viewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! ViewController
viewController.btn_stop.hidden = false // Found nil error
```

But even in this case it will find nil. The viewController is instantiated but not loaded yet. You should probably unhide the button in the viewDidLoad function of the ViewController.